# Escape/Special Characters from user input to HTML5 data-attributes using URL Encode/Decode

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, custom-data-attribute

This is my first question on stackoverflow - needing help from all you experts. Our web app allows the user to input escape/special characters. We are doing some testing for extreme cases. I'm able to pass the escape characters through ajax/json.

```js
var test = JSON.stringify({
  typeName: $("#typeName").val(),
  invoiceType: 'NewTypeArea'
});
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "BackEnd/WebService.php",
  data: {
    newInvoice: test
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My backend developer does their thing with escape/special characters.  When I make another call I get the following JSON data

```
[{"propName":"Special '\"'\\","typeName":"type'\"\\"}]
```

This data returned is correct. For simplicity - I have only one object for this example - I take this data and put it into a dropdown list.

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
var output = '<option class="type" id="' + this.qfInvoiceNum + '" value="' + this.typeName + '">' + this.typeName +'</option>';
$('select#typeList').append(output);
```

});

It displays all the escape/special characters correctly. For instance:  "type'\"\" displays as type'\"\

The user then selects one of the list items. I've tried capturing the typeName numerous ways with data-attributes, value, etc. Here is one example:

```
$( '.selectChange1').change(function() {
typeGrab = $('select option.type:selected').val();
pullArea();
});
```

But this is where the problem comes in. If they select a list item with special/escape characters the value from the console returns

```
"type'"
```

not

```
"type'\"\\"
```

So of course when I pass in the var typeGrab for the JSON/AJAX call it is wrong.

Is there a good solution on on how to get escape/special characters from a dropdown? Or maybe I'm going wrong with $.each when I loop through the data? Or, quite possibly, I'm missing something very simple. Any help or insight would be great.

Thank you.

Additional Info.  The first solution does work. However, I didn't use this initially due to the fact that there are a couple of times where the displayed text is not what I want to grab - which is why I was trying data*-attributes.

For example:

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
var output = '<option id="' + this.qfInvoiceNum + '" class="type" data-index="' + this.typeName + '" >' + this.typeName +' | #' + this.qfInvoiceNum +'</option>';
$('select#typeList').append(output);
});
```

If I want the value of this.typeName with escape/special characters the provided solution does not work.  I can't use data-attributes or the html option value.

However, after much research, I found a great solution for this problem if you are looking to pass in values to data-attributes that have escape/special characters.  Please my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much research I found the solution I was looking for. If you want to use escape/special characters in html5 data-attributes than a great solution would be to use encodeURI()/decodeURI(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

Solution for this question:

Encoded url version of the value and set the value for select:

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
     var uri = val.typeName;
     var res = encodeURI(uri);
     var output = '<option id="' + this.qfInvoiceNum + '" class="type" data-name="' + res + '" >' + this.typeName +' | #' + this.qfInvoiceNum +'</option>';
     $('select#typeList').append(output);
    });
```

On select, grab the encoded uri, then decode uri

```
$('.selectChange2').change(function() {
    uriTypeGrab = $('select option.type:selected').data('name');
    typeGrab = decodeURI(uriTypeGrab);
});
```

typeGrab is now in the correct format with all of the escape/special characters and ready to pass to JSON.stringify() for the ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty sure to have really understood the whole question. Anyway, here is what I point out as perforce causing some issues.

When you create an `<option>` like this one:

```
'<option class="type" id="' + this.qfInvoiceNum + '" value="' + this.typeName + '">' + this.typeName +'</option>'
```

then `this.typeName` is used to populate both `value` attribute and node content.

In the latter case all is fine, as you reported, since the current `typeName` content has nothing special here, at the HTML point of view.

But in the `value` attribute, the content goes inside of quotes, and here it cannot be neutral as well.

Without more deeper analyzing and testing I can't be strictly affirmative, but a first, quite simply, attempt would be not to populate `value` attribute at all, using the HTML capability to transparently infer `option` value from its node content when no `value` has been given.

This way, the content should escape the constraints of the formulation in writing `value`. Let me know if it worked...

Comment: I found the solution I was looking for.  I updated the bottom part of my question and answered below.  I do appreciate your help as it clarified what I was trying to accomplish.  Thank you! @cFreed

Comment: Yes! Congratulations: sure this new way is the true good way. Thanks for the feedback, and to have taken the time to clearly expose the final solution in your own answer: it is a valuable clarification to any further reader.